# How to scan multiple directories with QDirIterator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

This will iterate one directory and the subdirectories , but how can I specify     "C:/" and "D:/" and so on? I want to specify multiple directories. Is this possible?

```
QDirIterator it("C:/", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << it.next();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native method to do what you want but you can do it in the following way.

```
QStringList list;
list<< "C:/" << "D:/";

foreach (QString element, list) {
    QDirIterator it(element, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        qDebug() << it.next();

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I did. Thanks.